# Adding seperate header/footer in each page using DOM in aspose.words

Tags: dom, aspose.words

I am using Document Object Model to create docx from XHTML. 
I am able to create the document with one two sections in common (one for the body and another one for the header and footer which has the first page different option enabled).
Now since we have a requirement to create different headers and footers for different pages. I am not sure how to do that using DOM.
In normal word document for creating different header and footer we need to break each page as page break and then in header and footer it would show as differnt sections to which we can disable the "linktoprevious" option and create different header footer for differnt pages.
I was wondering if there is any way that aspose.words would recognize each page automatically and based on that we could create section break (Next Page) while reading the document.

Or let me know if there is any possible way to create different header and footer for each page using Document Object MOdel in aspose.words .Net

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, but doable with Aspose.Words using the LayoutCollector API, that finds the page number of a node. The idea is to loop through each run in the document and insert a section break, at the last node of each page. Try the sample code below, it works with a file containing only text/paragraphs at my end.

```
// Load document
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(src);
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Get all runs
NodeCollection runs = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true);
foreach(Run run in runs)
{
    // Find the page number
    LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(doc);
    int pageNumber = collector.GetEndPageIndex(run);

    // If next run is on next page, add a page break
    Node nextNode = run.ParentNode.NextSibling;
    if (nextNode == null)
        continue;
    int nextPageNumber = collector.GetStartPageIndex(nextNode);

    if (nextPageNumber > pageNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add a break here.");
        builder.MoveTo(run);
        builder.InsertBreak(BreakType.SectionBreakNewPage);

        // Modify header footer
        Section currentSection = builder.CurrentSection;
        builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);
        builder.Write("Header of page " + nextPageNumber);
        builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.FooterPrimary);
        builder.Write("Footer of page " + nextPageNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Saqib but is there any other way we could do this **without page break**?? Also it is taking very long time to read the document and generate the output. Is there any other way to do it while creating the document itself? I dnt wanna read the document again just for creating different headers and footers. It would **take a lot of time**..

Comment: You can use collector.GetEndPageIndex(node) method while creating every object in the document. If the page number changes, add a section break.

Comment: Razzq thank you for your comment. I will try it and let you know if any problem comes. :)