# Aspose Word custom Footer for each page

Tags: java, footer, aspose, aspose.words

What would be the correct approach to set specific Footer/Header per page using Aspose.Word library (in Java)? Consider the Document which has different number of Sections and Pages.

I did some tries with the Document having 2 Pages in Section 1 and singe page for rest sections. As far as I understood the document should have equal number of sections and pages in order to set custom Footer per page.

I suppose the part of final solution is here [Adding seperate header/footer in each page using DOM in aspose.words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098635/adding-seperate-header-footer-in-each-page-using-dom-in-aspose-words)

However, this code does not work correct as all footer texts get be written on the single page's footer. Moreover the number of recognised pages is higher that actual is.

**Update 2023-10-24**

This is the method which should add custom footer, but nothing really is added to footer.

```
private void addCustomFooter() {
        var collector = new LayoutCollector(builder.getDocument());
        NodeCollection<Paragraph> paragraphs = builder.getDocument().getChildNodes(NodeType.PARAGRAPH, true);
        log.info("Paragraphs total count={}", paragraphs.getCount());
        int pageIndex = 1;
        for (final Paragraph para : paragraphs) {
            if (collector.getStartPageIndex(para) == pageIndex) {
                log.info("Paragraph, pageIndex={}", pageIndex);
                builder.moveTo(para.appendChild(new Run(builder.getDocument())));
                builder.insertBreak(BreakType.SECTION_BREAK_CONTINUOUS);
                pageIndex++;
            }
        }
        pageIndex = 1;
        
        for (final Section section : builder.getDocument().getSections()) {
            log.info("Section. pageIndex={}", pageIndex);
            var headerFooterType = HeaderFooterType.FOOTER_PRIMARY;
            HeaderFooter footer = section.getHeadersFooters().getByHeaderFooterType(headerFooterType);
            if (footer == null) {
                footer = new HeaderFooter(builder.getDocument(), headerFooterType);
                section.getHeadersFooters().add(footer);
            }
            builder.moveToSection(builder.getDocument().getSections().indexOf(section));
            builder.moveToHeaderFooter(headerFooterType);
            builder.write("Page: " + pageIndex);
            pageIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, in MS Word document headers/footers are defined per section. Each section in MS Word document can have 3 types of header and footer - `First`, `Primary` and `Even` pages. In your case it is required to split document by pages, you can achieve this using [Document.ExtractPages](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/document/#extractPages-int-int). For example see the following code:

```java
Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx");

// Clone source document.
Document result = (Document)doc.deepClone(false);

// Split and rejoin document by pages.
for (int i = 0; i < doc.getPageCount(); i++)
{
    Document page = doc.extractPages(i, 1);
    // Remove old Header/Footer
    for (Section s : page.getSections())
    {
        s.getHeadersFooters().clear();
        s.getPageSetup().setOddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter(false);
        s.getPageSetup().setDifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter(false);
    }
    // Add new header to the first section of page.
    DocumentBuilder pageBuilder = new DocumentBuilder(page);
    pageBuilder.moveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HEADER_PRIMARY);
    pageBuilder.write("This is specific header for " + i + " page");

    result.appendDocument(page, ImportFormatMode.USE_DESTINATION_STYLES);
}

result.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx");
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution really works. I was just considering about cloning the original document. I would prefer the way to turn every page into the section and set corresponding footer/header, but my method does not work for some reason. I cannot find why nothing is written to the footer.

Comment: The original document is cloned to preserve the original document styles and compatibility options. When `result.appendDocument` method is used each section of the appended "sub-document" is appended to the end of the `result`.